# How can I make my form full screen with the TForm.FullScreen property?

Tags: delphi, fullscreen, firemonkey, tform

I am trying to use the `FullScreen` property of `TForm` in a FireMonkey app in Delphi, but `FullScreen := true` doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Which platform(s)?

Comment: I am using the 10.3

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"?

Comment: Plus you did not answer which platform(s), i.e. are you having this issue when the app runs on Windows, iOS, Android etc?

Comment: Just win32. I just added a button to test it and when i use fullscreen:=true; nothing happens. When I change the value from the properties the form goes to fullscreen when I run my program.

Comment: Ok this is what I get when I try fullscreen:=true; E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMenuItem' and 'Boolean'

Comment: Fullscreen is supposed to accept a boolean so I dont know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Do you have a menu item named `fullscreen`? If so, change its name.

Comment: Thank you for helping me guys. @BrakNicku is right. I had a menu item named fullscreen. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From information you've provided in comments:

> Ok this is what I get when I try `fullscreen:=true;` 
>   E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMenuItem' and 'Boolean'

it appears you have a menu item whose name is `fullscreen`, and it's causing a scope mismatch. This would also explain why it works fine when you change the property in the Object Inspector, but won't compile when you try to do it in code.

Change the menu item's `Name` in the Object Inspector. The `TMenuItem.Caption` can be `Fullscreen`, but the `Name` should be something else that does not  conflict with an existing property of the form itself.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you for helping.